# pyqt5 работа с объектами

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt5

Просьба показать на примере этой программы как правильно взаимодействовать с полями. Я пытался найти пример как взять с одного поля текст и по нажатию кнопки перенести его во второе поле, но никак не могу найти толковое объяснение.

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(664, 343)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 301, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 301, 41))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 10, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 60, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 664, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def clickButton1(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

так же, было бы неплохо, получить пример работы с другими окнами, к примеру, как сделать такое же действие но перенести эту надпись в другое окно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(664, 343)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 301, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 301, 41))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 301, 41))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 10, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 60, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 110, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 664, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def clickButton1(self):
        pass


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_1)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_2)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_3)

    def clicked_button_1(self):
        # добавление текста в textEdit2
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText(self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText())

    def clicked_button_2(self):
        # добавление текста в textEdit
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(self.ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText())

    def clicked_button_3(self):
        # Создание сообщения в новом окне
        self.w = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.w.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.ui.textEdit_3.toPlainText())
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.w.label)
        self.w.setLayout(layout)
        self.w.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А можно как то сделать заготовленное окно в том же qt designer и при нажатии на кнопку перенести из поля текст в новое окно в нужное место?

Comment: @kkkkkkkk может и возможно (хотя я сомневаюсь потому что `qt designer` кажется только делает формы и их подстараивает под вашу идею), но как по мне намного проще сделать это отдельным кодом